# Codename One TextField.addDataChangedListener on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I have a simple programme that has a TextField.

On the TextField I have added a addDataChangedListener.

Using the simulator the addDataChangedListener is called every time a key is pressed. However, once installed on an Android device this function stops.

Thanks

Comment: please add code so it would be easy to suggest.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an uncaught or swallowed exception as @akashkubavat mentioned this does work on Android. Check that there are no catch blocks without error logging and try to connect the device with a cable to view its output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem to(could) be Codename One does not recognise the Enter key(keycode 13)

```
form.addKeyListener(48, (ActionListener) (ActionEvent evt) -> {
        System.out.println("0");
    });
form.addKeyListener(13, (ActionListener) (ActionEvent evt) -> {
        System.out.println("Enter");
    });
```

Pressing 0 outputs "0" however pressing Enter does nothing...

The simulator refreshes the page when you press enter so gives the illusion that the textField was accepting the Enter input.

Comment: I think then you may have to use TextArea if you want 'enter' in content.

Comment: That would be the ideal solution, however being able to read the keys as they are input will work for me, thanks

Comment: Keys applies to physical keys not the virtual keyboard

Comment: Yes, I am using a USB keyboard

Answer (score 1):

compare your code with this. THis is working for me on Android and iOS

`findTaCount(f).addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {
            public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
                //do your action/validations
            }
        });`
where findTaCount is textfield for me.

Remember to add f (optional though, but good to have)

Good luck!

Update:
I have added it in beforeXXForm() method.